# Visual Studio skips lines of code

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, debugging, dll

I have been working on a program in which I use the EnumWindows function to detect active Windows and save their handles in a list.
Now, everytime I run what I have so far the debugger just skips the line with the EnumWindows function without returning an error.

Is there something wrong with my code? Or do I have to get an additional library to access this function? Hope someone knows how to fix this
Here is the code of the class which contains EnumWindows:

```
Center :: Center(int initInterval) : interval(initInterval)
{
    detectWindows();
}

int Center :: getInterval()
{
    return interval;
}
void Center :: setInterval(int intrvl)
{
    interval = intrvl;
}

void Center :: initializeDisplays()
{

}

void Center :: detectWindows()
{
    EnumWindows(detectWindowsProc, (LPARAM)&windowList);  //Debugger skips this line
}
```

Comment: Can you give us more information about what you mean by "skips this line"? Are you single stepping through the program? Are you stepping into the `detectWindows` method?

Comment: msvcp120d.i386.pbd is only for steppng into the VS specific code which you don't need here. EnumWindows also - you don't need the pdb file. Here you JUST need the pdb file for your executable. If it is out of sync, then either you have a threading issue or pdbs don't match. I dont know what version of VS you are using but you can see loaded PDBs and their paths - id check the one for your executable VS 2013. Try the following debug->Winddows->Modules (See my edit below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by 'skips the line'? The debugger will step over it, execute it, but will not be able to step in to it because you have no debug information available for the windows functions. Normally if you put a breakpoint in your `detectWindowsProc` that breakpoint should be hit. Provided there are windows to enumerate, `EnumWindows` has some strange quirks, see MSDN and comments there for more info:
[EnumWindows function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response, it looked like it skipped it but I just tried to set the breakpoint into the detectWindowsProc function instead of infront of the EnumWindows function. It showed that it now actually stepped into the detectWindowsProc function and then suddenly jumps to a screen saying: "msvcp120d.i386.pbd not loaded - No Symbols loaded". Is there a way to fix this? And does this mean it actually executes the EnumWindows function properly and just can't find any windows? I have used similar code in Python using PyWin with it working perfectly..

Comment: If you don't have the pdb files you cannot debug the part (Maybe you can obtain them?). Please refer to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database). The`EnumWindows` function jumps to code which you don't have and for which you don't have debug info. That logic then calls your callback `detectWindowsProc` and when that finishes it continues its own logic to finaly jump back to your 'detectWindows`. If `detectWindowsProc` is called it seems everything is working fine, you just don't have debug info in the middle.

Answer (score 3):

Code shouldn't be just skipped, typically this is a sign of your source/exe/ and PDB files being out of sync. Clean your project and try again (remove all .exe, obj, pdbs) and ensure you are doing a debug build.

Check Debug->Windows->Modules. I just tested a similar scenario, worked fine on breakpoints. Check the timestamp of your PDB as shown here to ensure its up to date
[image]

Comment: we're saying the same thing :) "and ensure you are doing a debug build."

Answer (score 0):

I also had face this issue. For me .pdb file was not in sync with .dll
I updated the dll and pdb and issue was fixed.

Comment: Adam's answer already included this advice, including how to check whether they are up to date and how to update those files. Also, an answer was accepted in 2016; there isn't any reason to add another answer here.